# Kio estas la signifo de "pli farinta"?

Tags: translation

Kunteksto: "la franca verkisto Romain Rolland tuj bonvenigis la supozatan decidon "historia evento, kies sekvoj estos grandegaj; ĝi estos **pli farinta** por la homara Internacio ol ĉiuj teoriaj diskutoj, aŭ disputoj de partioj en kiuj absorbiĝas la agado de la okcidenta socialismo ..."

Comment: Kiu verkis tion? Cxu eblas trovi la originalan citajxon de Romain Rolland?

Answer (score 8):

Eble la signifo estos pli klara, se vi iom rearanĝas la frazon:
Ĝi estos farinta pli por la homara Internacio ol ĉiuj teoriaj diskutoj.
It will have done more for ...

Answer (score 4):

La problemo estas, ke *pli* estas plejofte uzata antaŭ adjektivoj: *pli bona, pli granda, ktp.* Tial ni ne tre kutimas vidi ĝin kiel kvantindikon ĉe verboj, kaj eĉ tiam, pli ofte ĝi estas uzata *post* la verbo: *”Ludoviko faris multon, sed Klara faris pli”*

Participoj estas verboj kun adjektiva masko, do, en kazoj kiel *pli farinta,* multaj parolantoj tuj pensas pri grado de adjektivo, kaj ne pri kvanto de rezulto de verbo.

Tamen, tiu kaj similaj esprimoj estas tute bonaj. Teorie, estas nenio kontraŭ ili. Praktike, tamen, ili estas maloftaj kaj do iom malklaraj por kelkaj. Eble oni evitu ilin en facila stilo, aŭ menciu la objekton pli komplete: *ĝi estos **farinta pli multon** por la homara Internacio, ol...*

Answer (score 2):

Mi trovis interrete la [jenan klarigon](https://www.resolveask.com/questions/130075/kio-estas-la-signifo-de-pli-farinta):

> Tio estas eraro; la ĝusta vorto estas farinda, el far- + -ind- + -a.

Mi samopinias kun la klarigo de Paŭl Peeraerts, sed la frazo pri kiu Xu Jie demandas estas iom ambigua, tiel ke eblas uzi kaj *farinta* kaj *farinda*. Mi ne pensas ke *pli farinta* estas malĝusta, sed eble ĝi estas tiom malofte uzata, ke estas malfacile kompreni ĝin unuavide. Jen aliaj ekzemploj:

> [The Esperantist, No. 25, November, 1905](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38240/38240-h/vol2/e211.htm): Ne, via Moŝto. Kompata
>   Antaŭzorgo estas **pli farinta** por fondi mian senkulpecon, ol ia plua
>   parolado miaparte.
>
> [Kardinalo](http://www.ipernity.com/blog/161260/328554): Post morto de kardinalo Riŝeljeo, en Parizon
>   ĉirkaŭiris sekva epigrafo: "Tie poreterne ripozas fama kardinalo **pli**
>   **farinta** malbonon ol bonon. Tio kio estas bono li faris malbone, tamen
>   la malbonon li faris bone."

Miakomprene, *pli farinta* signifas io aŭ iu, kiu pli faris, faras aŭ faros (depende de la intencita tempo). Eble estus pli facile kompreni tiujn frazojn se oni uzus simplajn verbotempojn anstataŭ kompleksajn:

*Ĝi **pli faros** por la homara Internacio ol ĉiuj teoriaj diskutoj.*

*Kompata Antaŭzorgo **pli faras** por fondi mian senkulpecon, ol ia plua parolado miaparte.*

*Tie poreterne ripozas fama kardinalo, **kiu pli faris** malbonon ol bonon.*

Comment: Por scii, ĉu la originalo devis havi _farinda_ anstataŭ _farinta_ oni bezonas pli da kunteksto. Laŭ mia kompreno, _-os -inta_ estas ĉi tie tute bona, kaj _-os -inda_ multe malpli: se oni celus indecon, oni uzus as-tempon, do _estas farinda._ Sed mi ripetas, sen pli da kunteksto certeco ne eblas.

Comment: Senrigarde la kuntekston, Tekstaro jam montras ke _-os -inda_ (11 trafoj) estas multe malpli ofta ol _-as -inda_ (298 trafoj). Tio konfirmas vian supran aserton. Aliflanke, la ofteco inter _-os -inta_ kaj _-as -inta_ estas tre simila (175 kontraŭ 168 respektive).